# Why is Java 8 slower to warm up

Tags: java, performance, tomcat

In our efforts to move from Java 6 (u39) to Java 8 (u51) we are facing an issue of longer warm up times for Java 8 compared to 6.

We noticed this both with a performance test run as a Java program and also for the initial requests when starting Tomcat 7 (u35) with Java 8.

We are running on a Linux Redhat 64 bit system.

I am sorry I do not have any isolated test case.

Regarding the performance test program I found that Java 6 came close to steady state performance of around 215 milliseconds in 10 iterations whereas Java 8 was taking 800 milliseconds after 10 iterations and took 70+ iterations to reach 215 ms.

When we ran JMeter tests at a concurrency of 10 on our tomcat webapp (with Spring 2.5, jackson, xerces XML parser, jedis etc.) immediately after re-starting Java 6 took less than a minute to give steady state performance whereas Java 8 took around 5-6 minutes and was slower by several orders of magnitude till then.

Turning off Tiered Compilation using -XX:-TieredCompilation VM HotSpot option in Java 8 fixed the warm up issue with the performance test Program with no change in steady state performance. This is surprising since Tiered Compilation is actually supposed to give faster warm up.

However turning off Tiered Compilation did not give similar improvement in warm up time for the Tomcat server.

I welcome any suggestion to fix this issue since deploying a new build in a live environment can become a hassle with a long warm up time.

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: Sounds similar to the differece between "-server" and "-client" configurations.  You might want to add the "java.*" system properties for both configurations to your question.

Comment: (as reported by your application - not those you set yourself)

Comment: This question might get a better response on the Stack Exchange channel [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) and/or [Super User](http://superuser.com/) as this sounds more like a server software and configuration issue than a programming challenge.

Answer (score 1):

> This is surprising since Tiered Compilation is actually supposed to give faster warm up.

You're confusing time-to-peak-performance and time-to-initialized/responsive-application.

+Tiered

- Interpreter (Tier 0) -> C1 (Tier 1-3) -> C2 (Tier 4)
- heavy C2 work gets delayed to a later point of time
- more time spent in C1-compiled code means type profiles after application startup might be cleaner, allowing for better optimization and fewer decompilations in C2
- Application can serve its first request sooner / reaches user interactivity / shortlived java executions finish sooner

-Tiered

- Interpreter -> C2
- Hot code may reach peak performance sooner
- Initialization and merely-warm code may take longer
- Less time spent profiling may under some circumstances lead to slightly suboptimal code

Another thing to play with is the number of compiler threads (`CICompilerCount`). The performance tradeoffs are complicated, so simply benchmarking various settings can be helpful.

Comment: Update: The marked difference in Java 8 warm up time could not be reproduced. It must have been due to an external environment difference.

Comment: We still continued to see a 10-15% longer time to steady state in Java 8 but nothing like an order of difference.

We have successfully moved entirely to Java 8.

After moving we found an issue with running out of Metaspace due to it growing without bounds. Limiting the Metaspace gave a runtime error and not limiting it got the Java process killed by Linux OOM Killer.

The issue turned out to be due to the old 10g Oracle JDBC driver and went away when we upgraded to the latest 11 g driver recommended on Oracle web site for Java 8.